# "Your password has expired" after restart mysql when updated mysql 5.7.8-rc(debian)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

echo time login in mysql shell it shows:

```
ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.
```

and error log shows:
`Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.`

Answer (score 5):

### MySQL password expired

Typically, in a script shell, you get the message: "Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords."

From MySQL 5.7.4 to 5.7.10, the default value for the `default_password_lifetime` variable is 360 (a year). For those versions, if you make no changes to this variable or individual user accounts, all user passwords will expire after 360 days.

To prevent automatic password expiry log in as root:

`mysql -u root -p`

then, for *clients that automatically connect to the server* (e.g. from scripts.) change the password expiration settings for those clients:

`ALTER USER 'script'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;`

*or* just disable automatic password expiration for *all users*:

`SET GLOBAL default_password_lifetime = 0;`

#### Links and resources:

[MySQL: Password Expiration and Sandbox Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-expiration-sandbox-mode.html)
[MySQL: Password Expiration Policy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-expiration-policy.html)
[Password expiration policy in MySQL Server 5.7](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2014/03/31/password-expiration-policy-in-mysql-server-5-7/)

Comment: Caveat: if I use `SET GLOBAL…` and the script or database changes (say with `alembic upgrade…` I have to do it again. I have yet to try `ALTER USER…` for that specific script.

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable the [Sandbox Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-expiration-sandbox-mode.html) for your connection. For the mysql CLI there is a [parameter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_connect-expired-password) to specify it:

```
mysql -u <user> [other params] --connect-expired-password
```

You then have to use the [SET PASSWORD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-password.html) statement to reset your password (it is allowed to reset it to its current value).

Comment: thx, can I get rid of  SET PASSWORD after restart mysqld ?

Comment: @lasteye the message pops up because your password was marked as expired, with the `SET PASSWORD` you reset it so it should not happen again (unless it is expired again by some command). You should then be able to reconnect normally even without server restart.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://www.diariodeunprogramador.net/fallo-al-conectar-mysql-your-password-expired/) works for me:

In CMD or in LINUX terminal, login as a root:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

then you deactivate the automatic expiration of passwords of all the users:

```
SET GLOBAL default_password_lifetime = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `my.cnf` change this:

```
[mysqld]
default_password_lifetime=180
```

to this:

```
[mysqld]
default_password_lifetime=0
```

And then restart your mysql server: `service mysql restart`

Changing line `default_password_lifetime` will affect global setting for all users on server so do that only if it's desired. This solution is advanced by official [MySQL 5.6 Password Expiration Policy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/password-expiration-policy.html).