# MySql global variable disconnect_on_expired_password

Tags: mysql-5.7, password

This is very annoying....
`disconnect_on_expired_password` is set to `ON`.
`MySql` version is:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.5-m15 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I need to understand which of my `MySql` users is causing this error:
 `[Note] Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.`

I tried setting default password lifetime to 0 so:
`SET GLOBAL default_password_lifetime = 0;` according to 
[MySQL password expired](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160430/51130), and `default_password_lifetime` now shows `360` and still I get the error.

I tried setting `disconnect_on_expired_password` but with no luck.
`SELECT @@GLOBAL.disconnect_on_expired_password;`
Gives:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.disconnect_on_expired_password |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                       1 |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

So I tried:
`SET GLOBAL disconnect_on_expired_password=0;
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'disconnect_on_expired_password' is a read only variable`

My questions are:

1. how can I know which of my `MySql` users is causing the error mentioned above?
2. how can I change `disconnect_on_expired_password` if @all??

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

1. This should give you a good idea as to which mysql user(s) is/are causing the error:

   `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE password_expired = 'Y';`
2. To change disconnect_on_expired_password: Edit /etc/my.cnf, find the `mysqld` section, add this line:

   `disconnect_on_expired_password=OFF`

   Then restart mysqld.